# What does istioctl x command refers to?

Tags: istio

I see in the official documentation references to [commands](https://istio.io/v1.8/docs/setup/upgrade/canary/) starting with `istioctl x ...` but there is not official definition for the usage of `x`.

As far as I can infer from the istioctl [manual](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/commands/istioctl/#istioctl-experimental), it appears to be a shorthand for `experimental`.

The command `istioctl | grep x` does not show any reference to the `x` usage neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct - `x` is shorthand for `experimental`.

You can see more information if you issue `istioctl x` without any additional commands:

```text
$ istioctl x
Experimental commands that may be modified or deprecated

Usage:
  istioctl experimental [command]

Aliases:
  experimental, x, exp
...
```